# Clonezilla or what else?

Tags: linux, embedded-linux

For embedded linux device , based on x86 processor, I need to program on it's internal memory the same linux image (it's not a standard image, I started from Ubuntu basic installation and customized it). What is the best way to do this ?

Prepare a full system and clone it with clonezilla or what else ?

Many thanks

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a programming question. It may be on topic at https://superuser.com/ or https://unix.stackexchange.com/. However, "what is best" without defining the meaning of "best" isn't going to be well-received on any site on this network.

Comment: Many thanks Lundins for your commet. I'll rewrite better my question and I'll ask on superuser.com and unix.stackexchange. as you advice me.